# How do I change a value in the leaderstats via touching a part? (Roblox)

Tags: roblox

Here's the error and what I've tried.
Error: `Workspace.Part.Script:4: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'`
My code:

Making Leaderstats:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local ls = Instance.new("Model")
    ls.Name = "leaderstats"
    ls.Parent = plr
 
    local m = Instance.new("IntValue")
    m.Name = "Stars"
    m.Value = 0
    m.Parent = ls

end)
```

Touch Code:

```
    local collected = false
    script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function()
        if collected == false then
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Stars.Value = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Stars.Value + 1
        end
        collected = true

end)
```

Answer (score 0):

A server script would suit your need better. In a localscript, the change would only appear for the player. Also, it's better practice to use the `Players` service offered by Roblox. Here's an example:

```lua
local Players = game:GetService('Players')

local collected = false
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(partTouched)
    if partTouched.Parent:IsA('Model') and partTouched.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid') and partTouched:IsA('BasePart') then -- Is this a player? If so, then..
        local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(partTouched.Parent)
        
        if collected == false then
            player.leaderstats.Stars.Value += 1 -- shorter syntax
        end
        
        collected = true
        --script.Parent:Destroy()   optional if this part won't be used again.
    end
end)
```

If you're planning to use this for many parts, using a central ModuleScript would save you lots of changing things back and forth: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ModuleScript