# How to make other scripts change leaderstats?

Tags: lua, roblox

im playing roblox and i wanna make a script so when you sell your capacity your money goes up by that amount. ill provide all scripts below.

```
local MaxCapacity = 5 --sets the maximum amount of times you can click. (can change)
local Capacity = 0 --the default capacity (dont change)
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    if Capacity < 5 then -- change the number to your max capacity
        Capacity = Capacity + 1
        print((Capacity))
    else
        if Capacity == 5 then -- change the number to your max capacity
            print("you have reached max capacity, go sell it.")
        end
    end
end)
```

-- the sell script:

```
game.Workspace["sell part"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if Capacity == 0 then
        print("you must have at least 1 capacity to sell.")
    else
        Capacity = 0
        print("you just sold your capacity")
        print(script.Parent.Parent)
    end
end)
```

-- the leaderboard script

```
local players = game:GetService('Players')

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    if player then
        local folder = Instance.new('Folder')
        folder.Name = 'leaderstats'
        folder.Parent = player
        local gold = Instance.new('IntValue')
        gold.Name = 'Caps'
        gold.Parent = folder
    end
end)
```

Comment: What isn't working? What do you expect to be happening, what is actually happening?

Comment: well what it does is it absolutley gets rid of my leaderboard and messes up the whole script. theres no error message its just as if the script doesnt exist. I expect it to do what i typed in the first part of the question

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013498/how-do-i-change-a-value-in-the-leaderstats-via-touching-a-part-roblox

Comment: no not really...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.
I combined the sell and first script into a LocalScript inside of the tool. I did not change the leaderboard script.
the tool LocalScript:

```lua
local MaxCapacity = 5 --sets the maximum amount of times you can click. (can change)
local Capacity = 0 --the default capacity (dont change)


script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    if Capacity < 5 then -- change the number to your max capacity
        Capacity = Capacity + 1
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Caps.Value += 1
        print(Capacity)
    else
        if Capacity == 5 then -- change the number to your max capacity
            print("you have reached max capacity, go sell it.")
        end
    end
end)

game.Workspace["sell part"].ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if Capacity == 0 then
        print("you must have at least 1 capacity to sell.")
    else
        Capacity = 0
        print("you just sold your capacity")
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Caps.Value = 0
        print(script.Parent.Parent)
    end
end)
```