# How do I change leaderstats value on roblox?

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to test out a game that gives coins to the player(via leaderstats) when you touch this block. When I touch the block though, my leaderstats don't change and I don't get any errors. Heres my Script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDtjv.png)

Comment: Heyo, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013498/how-do-i-change-a-value-in-the-leaderstats-via-touching-a-part-roblox

Answer (score 0):

`game.Players` is a service and is not the `Player` who owns the `Character` that touched `TestPart`. The Players service provides a method to get the `Player` from a `Character` called `GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)`.

```
TestPart.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)

if plr then
plr.leaderstats.Coins.Value += 1
end
end)
```

Luau supports increments (`+=`) but not lua.